# Microservices: Ensure all the required kafka events are in place before beginning of enrichment

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, microservices, system-design

I have a product and its complete information is obtained from various JSON messages. In a Microservices architecture, how can I ensure all the required events are in place before I begin the enrichment of the product Json?

Event for Product:

```json
  {
    "eventType": {
      "eventName": "product",
      "createdBy": "systemUser"
    },
    "event": {
      "id": "PRAD-DHR72",
      "productName": "iPhone13",
      "offerStartDate": "01152023",
      "offerEndDate": "01152024",
      "productPrice": [
        {
          "id": "GOFGT-HDOYDS",
          "name": "STG-67925"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

For Product Pricing:

```json
  {
    "eventType": {
      "eventName": "productPrice",
      "createdBy": "systemUser"
    },
    "event": {
      "id": "GOFGT-HDOYDS",
      "name": "STG-67925",
      "offerStartDate": "01152023",
      "offerEndDate": "01152024",
      "price": 23.54,
      "discounts": {
        "id": "EADg-HEFR87",
        "name": "GHRD-TUFR7"
      }
    }
  }
```

For Product Availability;

```json
  {
    "eventType": {
      "eventName": "availability",
      "createdBy": "systemUser"
    },
    "event": {
      "id": "AVD-DEA78",
      "products": [
        "PRAD-DHR72",
        "PRAD-DHE72",
        "PRAD-DHG72",
        "PRAD-DHES2",
        "PRAD-DHE82",
        "PRAD-DHE42"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Enriched Product information:

productPrice is populated from the above event and isAvailable is set to true as the product is available in the availability event.

```json
{
  "id": "PRAD-DHR72",
  "productName": "iPhone13",
  "offerStartDate": "01152023",
  "offerEndDate": "01152024",
  "productPrice": [
    {
      "id": "GOFGT-HDOYDS",
      "name": "STG-67925",
      "offerStartDate": "01152023",
      "offerEndDate": "01152024",
      "price": 23.54,
      "discounts": {
        "id": "EADg-HEFR87",
        "name": "GHRD-TUFR7"
      }
    }
  ],
  "isAvailable": "true"
}
```

As one can observe, the enrichment can happen only when all the events are available. So how to I design a system where in I know all the events have been received and the enrichment can begin!!

Comment: Use the transactional-outbox or saga patterns

Comment: Give me few days time, I am new to all these, let me read through that and get back. Thanks.

Comment: This is trivial to implement with temporal.io.

Comment: Why do you need all three at the same time? product + price or product + availability could be enough to do **an** enrichment. When the 3rd piece arrives then you can enrich the semi (or partially) enriched json.

Comment: @PeterCsala, this is just one scenario, In further releases. There are other scenarios for eg,  you have multiple product offering price json and the price of the product is computed from it. So, we need to all the json before performing any of these functions.